# TrustStore fails to init but KeyStore successful

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I am trying to configure Tomcat so that my web application can use LDAPS. It all works fine on the UAT server but for some reason the production server cannot initialize the trust store.
I have turned on debugging (via `-Djavax.net.debug=all`) and the error is:

> default context init failed: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

I am 100% sure that the password is correct, as I have run keytool and listed the contents of the truststore, as well as taken the same file from the working UAT server.

As an experiment, I configured Tomcat to use the same store file for both keystore and truststore (I realise this is not a typical setup, but from my understanding the file formats etc are the same so they should both load):

`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=xxx
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\.keystore
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=xxx
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\.keystore`

and the keystore works:

> keyStore is : C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin.keystore 
>   keyStore type is : jks 
>   keyStore provider is : 
>  
>   init keystore 
>  init keymanager of type SunX509
>   *** 
>  found key for : tomcat

whilst the truststore fails.. for the *same file and password!*:

> trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin.keystore
>   trustStore type is : jks
>   trustStore provider is : 
>   init truststore
>   default context init failed: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

From the web application the stack trace has some more detail (whether it helps I'm not sure.. I studied the java source for TrustManagerFactoryImpl and matched it with the logging but it didn't explain the behaviour)

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: <ldap url>:636 [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mycompany.fde.util.LDAPHelper.initialBindSSL(LDAPHelper.java:116)
    at com.mycompany.fde.util.LDAPHelper.<init>(LDAPHelper.java:91)
    at com.mycompany.fde.util.LDAPHelper.getInstance(LDAPHelper.java:58)
    at com.mycompany.fde.server.work.StartupWork.startupStage1(StartupWork.java:224)
    at com.mycompany.fde.server.work.StartupWork.call(StartupWork.java:121)
    at com.mycompany.fde.server.work.StartupWork.call(StartupWork.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(Unknown Source)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.getCacertsKeyStore(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.getDefaultTrustManager(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    ... 45 more
```

I'm at a complete loss - any help/ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: From the stack trace, it looks like things are failing during `TrustManagerFactoryImpl.getCacertsKeyStore()`. If you look at `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security` on the server, can you see a file named `cacerts` there?

Comment: If the `cacerts` file is there, maybe its password is something else than the default, which is "changeit".

Comment: Yes I've tried letting it use `cacerts` (even after a fresh Java install) or `jssecacerts` but it always fails with the same error. This is why I have tried to use a custom store (same as the keystore which does load ok).

Comment: So what happens when you just omit `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` and `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` parameters entirely? You can also import certs to JVM's default trust store (`cacerts`) if you need a custom cert there for LDAP.

Comment: Same error unfortunately - debugging shows that it takes the default `cacerts` (or `jssecacerts` if I put one) but fails

Comment: Can you check that `cacerts` is using the default password, with `keytool -list -keystore %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts`?

Comment: Yes I've checked, it's using 'changeit'

Comment: Long shots but: same version of java on both machines? same cryptoproviders in JRE/lib/security/java.security plus modifications if any by code calling e.g. `Security.insertProviderAt()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help, I finally found that for some unknown reason, someone had indeed set the truststore password in `Catalina.properties` (via `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword`).  It seems that this takes priority even over the java variables set in the Tomcat UI :(

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, this can also occur if the identically configured keystore file does not exist (here: erreneous *file:///* prefix). It still leads to:

```
trustStore is: No File Available, using empty keystore.
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
keyStore is : file:///c:/my.jks
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is :
```

Compared to OpenJDK 1.8.0.181, the `keyStore is :` line just misleadingly outputs `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` [1] while the given `trustStore` is checked for existance first [2].

[1] sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl
[2] sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to supply the truststore password. So, don't.

NB `keytool -list` doesn't need the password at all, and it isn't proof you know the correct password. The error you're getting, on the other hand, *is* proof that the password is incorrect.

You should not use the same file for both keystore and truststore.

Comment: When your code calls `KeyStore.load` you can omit the password, but when `SSLContext` creates the default context it won't; your only choice is to specify the pw or let the default be used. Using the same file is a bad idea normally but here appears to be only for debugging.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I have acres of working code that proves otherwise. If the `SSLContext` uses the default password anywhereI have yet to either see it documented or encounter a situation that would be explained by it in 20 years of JSSE programming.